# How to handle React components that have intensive logic?

Tags: reactjs, architecture, refactoring

### Template Question

#### The Problem

Hey guys!

Recently I've been noticing some very logic-intensive react components being created in the application I work in, and this components usually have dozens of line that I call "setup logic" (variables that needs to be set before I render my component). Some of this stuff can be:

- Sending a request to the translation service to retrieve the required translated strings for that component
- Creating derived data from states, such as:

  - whether or not to show a component given a feature flag from the API
  - The percentage of a progress bar given an initial and final value received by the API
- Getting the currentUser
- Getting the default brand colours and font sizes
- Mutations/Queries that will be executed when the user clicks on a button
- Mapping all this info to styled components and child components

This begs the question of "Are we doing too much in these components?"

Undoubtedly yes, but how exactly do we break this apart? Where do we draw the line?

Ah, and a heads up, this is our setup currently:

**Stack info:**

Frontend: React

API: GraphQL

#### Possible Solution

Separating the setup logic (the getters, mappers and queries) from the presentation logic (the JSX).

**Question 1.** Should there be a component that's sole responsibility is to serve the presentation component with its logic?

**Question 2.** Should this be a component at all or should this logic be served by the graphQL API? How coupled should the GraphQL be to the React component?

#### Sample Code

This is an example that illustrates the issue:

```js
// 30 lines of *import*
// ...

const MyForm = ({
  onSubmit,
  initialValues,
  children,
  loading,
  isCreating,
  cycleId,
  permissions,
  otherPermissions,
  showWeightBalance,
  balance,
}) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const currentUser = useCurrentUser();
  const cycle = useCycle({ id: cycleId });
  const canUpdateFields =
    isCreating || (permissions && permissions.update);
  const canUpdateContributors =
    isCreating ||
    (permissions && permissions.updateContributors);
  const canReassignResponsible =
    isCreating ||
    (permissions && permissions.reassignResponsible);
  const canUpdateWeight =
    isCreating ||
    (otherPermissions &&
      otherPermissions.updateWeight);
  const canShowContributorsInput =
    isCreating ||
    (permissions && permissions.showContributorsInputOnForm);

  return (
    <Form
      initialValues={{
        name: {},
        description: {},
        type: {
          kind: kind.NUMBER,
          direction: direction.ASC,
        },
        baseValue: null,
        target: null,
        unit: null,
        weight: 1,
        progressCalculus: false,
        responsible: null,
        contributors: [],
        tasks: [],
        scale: null,
        ...initialValues,
      }}
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      key={JSON.stringify(initialValues)} // This is made to reset the form when new initial values get loaded, should be enableReinitialize but richtexteditor wouldn't reset
    >
      {formProps => (
        <Fragment>
          <FormFieldTextTranslations
            name="name"
            label={t('yml_path')}
            subtitle={t('yml_path')}
            placeholder={t('yml_path')}
            locales={locale.availableLocales()}
            validate={[
              requiredTranslation(t('yml_path')),
            ]}
            disabled={loading || !canUpdateFields}
          />
          <FormFieldRichTextTranslations
            name="description"
            label={t('yml_path')}
            subtitle={t('yml_path')}
            placeholder={t(
              'yml_path',
            )}
            locales={locale.availableLocales()}
            optional
            hideToolbar
            minimumLines={4}
          />
          <FormFieldGroup
            name="type"
            label={t('yml_path')}
            validate={[required('yml_path')]}
          >
            <Layout display="flex" flexWrap="wrap">
              <FormFieldRadio
                mr="px32"
                mb={['px8', 'none']}
                disabled={loading || !isCreating}
                name="type"
                value={{
                  kind: kind.NUMBER,
                  direction: direction.ASC,
                }}
                label={(checked, disabled, error) => (
                  <RadioCard
                    iconProps={{
                      iconName: 'chart-line',
                      solid: true,
                      fontSize: '20px',
                    }}
                    text={t(
                      'yml_path',
                    )}
                    checked={checked}
                    disabled={disabled}
                    error={error}
                  />
                )}
              />
              <FormFieldRadio
                mr="px32"
                mb={['px8', 'none']}
                disabled={loading || !isCreating}
                name="type"
                value={{
                  kind: kind.NUMBER,
                  direction: direction.DESC,
                }}
                label={(checked, disabled, error) => (
                  <RadioCard
                    iconProps={{
                      iconName: 'chart-line-down',
                      solid: true,
                      fontSize: '20px',
                    }}
                    text={t(
                      'yml_path',
                    )}
                    checked={checked}
                    disabled={disabled}
                    error={error}
                  />
                )}
              />
              <FormFieldRadio
                mr="px32"
                mb={['px8', 'none']}
                disabled={loading || !isCreating}
                name="type"
                value={{
                  kind: kind.KEEP,
                  direction: formProps.values.type.direction,
                }}
                label={(checked, disabled, error) => (
                  <RadioCard
                    iconProps={{
                      iconName: 'chart-keep',
                      solid: true,
                      fontSize: '20px',
                    }}
                    text={t('yml_path')}
                    checked={checked}
                    disabled={disabled}
                    error={error}
                  />
                )}
              />
              <FormFieldRadio
                mb={['px8', 'none']}
                disabled={loading || !isCreating}
                name="type"
                value={{
                  kind: kind.BINARY,
                  direction: null,
                }}
                label={(checked, disabled, error) => (
                  <RadioCard
                    iconProps={{
                      iconName: 'check',
                      solid: true,
                      fontSize: '20px',
                    }}
                    text={t(
                      'yml_path',
                    )}
                    checked={checked}
                    disabled={disabled}
                    error={error}
                    tooltip={t(
                      'yml_path',
                    )}
                  />
                )}
              />
            </Layout>
          </FormFieldGroup>
          {formProps.values.type.kind === kind.NUMBER &&
            formProps.values.type.direction === direction.ASC && (
              <AscendingForm
                formProps={formProps}
                loading={loading}
                canUpdateFields={canUpdateFields}
                canUpdateWeight={canUpdateWeight}
                showWeightBalance={showWeightBalance}
                balance={balance}
                isCreating={isCreating}
              />
            )}
          {formProps.values.type.kind === kind.NUMBER &&
            formProps.values.type.direction === direction.DESC && (
              <DescendingForm
                formProps={formProps}
                loading={loading}
                canUpdateFields={canUpdateFields}
                canUpdateWeight={canUpdateWeight}
                showWeightBalance={showWeightBalance}
                balance={balance}
                isCreating={isCreating}
              />
            )}
          {formProps.values.type.kind === kind.KEEP && (
            <KeepForm
              loading={loading}
              canUpdateFields={canUpdateFields}
              canUpdateWeight={canUpdateWeight}
              showWeightBalance={showWeightBalance}
              balance={balance}
              isCreating={isCreating}
            />
          )}
          {formProps.values.type.kind === kind.BINARY && (
            <BinaryForm
              loading={loading}
              canUpdateWeight={canUpdateWeight}
              showWeightBalance={showWeightBalance}
              balance={balance}
              isCreating={isCreating}
            />
          )}
          {cycle &&
            (cycle.allowCustomScore ||
              cycle.allowScale) &&
            formProps.values.type.kind !== kind.BINARY && (
              <FormFieldGroup
                name="progressCalculus"
                label={t('yml_path')}
                validate={[
                  required(t('yml_path')),
                ]}
              >
                <FormFieldRadio
                  name="progressCalculus"
                  mb="px4"
                  label={t(
                    'yml_path',
                  )}
                  disabled={loading || !isCreating}
                  value={false}
                />
                {cycle.allowCustomScore && (
                  <FormFieldRadio
                    name="progressCalculus"
                    mb="px4"
                    label={t(
                      'yml_path',
                    )}
                    disabled={loading || !isCreating}
                    value={ProgressCalculusEnum.customScore}
                  />
                )}
                {cycle.allowScoreScale && (
                  <Fragment>
                    <FormFieldRadio
                      name="progressCalculus"
                      mb="px4"
                      label={t(
                        'yml_path',
                      )}
                      disabled={loading || !isCreating}
                      value={ProgressCalculusEnum.scale}
                    />
                    <ScaleRadioHelperNegativeMargin>
                      <FieldHelper
                        message={t(
                          'yml_path',
                        )}
                        iconName="info-circle"
                      />
                    </ScaleRadioHelperNegativeMargin>
                  </Fragment>
                )}
              </FormFieldGroup>
            )}
          {isCreating &&
            cycle &&
            cycle.allowScoreScale &&
            formProps.values.type.kind === kind.NUMBER &&
            formProps.values.progressCalculus ===
              ProgressCalculusEnum.scale && (
              <ScoreScaleForm
                name="scale.partitions"
                formProps={formProps}
              />
            )}
          <FormFieldSelectContract
            name="responsible"
            label={t('yml_path')}
            placeholder={t(
              'yml_path',
            )}
            filter={{ active: true }}
            validate={[
              required(
                t('yml_path'),
              ),
            ]}
            disabled={loading || !canReassignResponsible}
            allowClear
          />
          <AssignToMeWrapper>
            <Button
              kind="primary"
              size="adaptative"
              appearance="text"
              onMouseDown={() => {
                setTimeout(
                  () =>
                    formProps.setFieldValue('responsible', {
                      key: currentUser.id,
                      label: currentUser.name,
                    }),
                  20,
                );
              }}
            >
              {t('assign_to_me')}
            </Button>
          </AssignToMeWrapper>
          {canShowContributorsInput && (
            <FormFieldSelectContract
              name="contributors"
              mode="multiple"
              label={t('yml_path')}
              placeholder={t(
                'yml_path',
              )}
              filter={{ active: true }}
              optional
              disabled={loading || !canUpdateContributors}
            />
          )}
          {isCreating && (
            <FormFieldGroup
              name="tasks"
              label={t('yml_path')}
              optional
            >
              <TasksForm name="tasks" tasks={formProps.values.tasks} />
            </FormFieldGroup>
          )}
          <Layout mt="px40">{children(formProps)}</Layout>
        </Fragment>
      )}
    </Form>
  );
};

export default MyForm;
```

Comment: You can create reusable function components to separate out repeated parts.

Comment: @Niraj that's a solid idea! Just to see if I understand, when you say `function components` do you mean `functional components`, or is there another concept i'm not aware of?

Cheers!

Comment: Yeah same functional components which are only responsible for taking props and return updated component when re-render.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create function components to separate out repeated parts so you can use as an element in your main component and also you can reuse it.